# how to make df[['col1']] a series

Tags: python, pandas

```
d = {'col1': [33,34], 'col2': [5,6]}
d1 = {'col1': [33,34], 'col2': [5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
type(df[['col1']])
```

the type above is a dataframe, how could I make it a series with minimal change?

Comment: Remove `[]` by `type(df['col1'])`

Answer (score 1):

Use single []s.

```
type(df['col1'])
```

Output:

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```